# Using braces in blocktrans

Tags: django, tags

How can I escape {{ or }} inside a `blocktrans` tag?

Solutions like {% verbatim %) or {% templatetag openvariable %} are not allowed inside a `blocktrans` tag.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it like this:

```
{% blocktrans with verbatim="your verbatim {{ text }}" %}
    Some stuff including {{ verbatim }}.
{% endblocktrans %}
```

This will preserve the braces around `{{ text }}`